# How to select the last child of each repeated series of classes using CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to create a chat application. Inside the chat container, I will add both sent and received messages. It is clear that the messages will not be in a specific order.

I need to add some margin at the end of each repeated series of sent or received messages.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="sent_message"></div>
   <div class="sent_message"></div>
   <!-- NEED MARGIN -->
   <div class="received_message"></div>
   <div class="received_message"></div>
   <div class="received_message"></div>
   <!-- NEED MARGIN -->
   <div class="sent_message"></div>
   <!-- NEED MARGIN -->
   <div class="received_message"></div>
   <!-- NEED MARGIN -->
   <div class="sent_message"></div>
   <div class="sent_message"></div>
   <!-- NEED MARGIN -->
</div>
```

Is there any CSS selector to select the `last-child` of each of the series of classes, or should I change the structure of the HTML?

Comment: What’sApp Web does it by adding a CSS class to each message that shouldn’t have a larger margin.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could select each `.received_message` [follwed by](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) a `.sent_message` and vice-versa, instead, using the selector `.received_message + .sent_message, .sent_message + .received_message`.

```css
.received_message + .sent_message, .sent_message + .received_message{
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.container div{
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px dashed white;
}
.received_message{
  background: rebeccapurple;
}
.sent_message{
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="sent_message"></div>
   <div class="sent_message"></div>
   <!-- NEED MARGIN -->
   <div class="received_message"></div>
   <div class="received_message"></div>
   <div class="received_message"></div>
   <!-- NEED MARGIN -->
   <div class="sent_message"></div>
   <!-- NEED MARGIN -->
   <div class="received_message"></div>
   <!-- NEED MARGIN -->
   <div class="sent_message"></div>
   <div class="sent_message"></div>
   <!-- NEED MARGIN -->
</div>
```